# How to access exactly 3rd array element (attr[2]) in JSP (array was passed into JSP from Servlet setAttribute())?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, enterprise

Say, I need to access in JSP *exactly 3rd element* from the array `new int[] {1,2,3,4}` passed from a Servlet below:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    request.setAttribute("attr2", new int[] {1,2,3});       

    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/my.jsp");
    try {
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know about `<c:forEach>` JSTL tag, **but I need something like `<c:out value="${attr2[2]}">`**

Comment: so is it not working? `<c:out value="${attr2[2]}">` ?